# What does the phrase "limit exists" graphically mean?

Tags: calculus, limits, intuition

I know that "limit exists" means the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit of a function are equal.

However, What does the phrase "limit exists" graphically mean?

What I understand is, "limit exists" means:

- the function is 'almost' continuous with a 'hole' on the curve

How can my above statement be reworded using 'mathematical' language?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: "the function is, at the very least, 'almost' continuous, possibly with a 'hole' on the curve" is a bit better. The limit exists at all the nice and continuous points too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, graphically speaking, "the limit of $f$ exists at $a$ if $f$ is continuous and defined on *at least* every point close to $a$."

I say "at least", because we can have definition and continuity at $a$, which is sufficient for the limit existing, but not necessary.